# Error in Iterating through Pandas DataFrame with if statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
   Id UserId    Name            Date                 Class  TagBased
0   2   23  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
1   3   22  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
2   4   21  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
3   5   20  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
4   6   19  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
```

I want to iterate through "TagBased" column and put the User Ids in a list where TagBased=True.
I have used the following code but I am getting no output which is incorrect because there are 18 True values in TagBased.

```
user_tagBased = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df['TagBased'] is True):
        user_TagBased.append(df['UserId'])
print(user_TagBased)

Output: []
```

Comment: try `df.loc[df['TagBased'],'UserId'].tolist()` you dont need loops most of the times in pandas

Comment: I am getting the following error by trying this method:   KeyError: "None of [Index(['False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False',\n       'False', 'False',\n       ...\n       'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False',\n       'False', 'False'],\n      dtype='object', length=18087)] are in the [index]"

Comment: better is `df.loc[df['TagBased'].eq("True"),'UserId'].tolist()` since the values are string

Comment: This one works, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others are suggesting, using Pandas conditional filtering is the best choice here without using loops! However, to still explain why your code did not work as expected:

You are appending `df['UserId']` in a for-loop while `df['UserId']` is a column. Same goes for `df['TagBased']` check, which is also a column.

I assume you want to append the userId at the current row in the for-loop.

You can do that by iterating through the df rows:

```
user_tagBased = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['TagBased'] == 'True': # Because it is a string and not a boolean here
        user_tagBased.append(row['UserId'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you don't need to use loops for this:

```
user_list = df[df['TagBased']==True]['UserId'].tolist()
print(user_list)

[19, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use any loop.

Note that:

- `df.TagBased` - yields a *Series* of *bool* type - *TagBased* column
  (I assume that *TagBased* column is of *bool* type).
- `df[df.TagBased]` - is an example of **boolean indexing** - it retrieves
  rows where *TagBased* is *True*
- `df[df.TagBased].UserId` - limits the above result to just *UserId*,
  almost what you want, but this is a *Series*, whereas you want a
  **list**.

So the code to produce your expected result, with saving in the destination
variable, is:

```
user_tagBased = df[df.TagBased].UserId.to_list()
```